# Conditional (Dynamic) Struct Tags

Tags: go

I'm trying to parse some xml documents in Go. I need to define a few structs for this purpose, and my struct tags depend on a certain condition.

Imagine the following code (even though I know it won't work)

```
if someCondition {
    type MyType struct {
        // some common fields
        Date    []string `xml:"value"`
    }
} else {
    type MyType struct {
        // some common fields
        Date    []string `xml:"anotherValue"`
    }
}

var t MyType
// do the unmarshalling ...
```

The problem is that these two structs have lots of fields in common. The only difference is in one of the fields and I want to prevent duplication. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That sounds like more of an XML Schema problem than a parsing problem. Those conditionals should actually be handled in the schema, and hence accordingly could be unmarshalled with one struct with conditional embedded structs.

Answer (score 2):

You use **different** types to unmarshal. Basically, you write the unmarshaling code twice and either run the first version or the second. There is no dynamic solution to this.

Comment: @HamidMohayeji No, you have to write code for each XML schema you have to process.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is probably to handle all possible fields and do some post-processing.

For example:

```
type MyType struct {
    DateField1    []string `xml:"value"`
    DateField2    []string `xml:"anotherValue"`
}

// After parsing, you have two options:

// Option 1: re-assign one field onto another:
if !someCondition {
    parsed.DateField1 = parsed.DateField2
    parsed.DateField2 = nil
}

// Option 2: use the above as an intermediate struct, the final being:
type MyFinalType struct {
    Date    []string `xml:"value"`
}

if someCondition {
    final.Date = parsed.DateField1
} else {
    final.Date = parsed.DateField2
}
```

**Note**: if the messages are sufficiently different, you probably want completely different types for parsing. The post-processing can generate the final struct from either.

Comment: Yes, this is the first thing I tried, but I was looking for a more efficient and elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

As already indicated, you must duplicate the field. The question is where the duplication should exist.

If it's just a single field of many, one option is to use embedding, and field shadowing:

```
type MyType struct {
    Date    []string `xml:"value"`
    // many other fields
}
```

Then when `Date` uses the other field name:

```
type MyOtherType struct {
    MyType // Embed the original type for all other fields
    Date     []string `xml:"anotherValue"`
}
```

Then after unmarshaling of `MyOtherType`, it's easy to move the `Date` value into the original struct:

```
type data MyOtherType
err := json.Unmarshal(..., &data)
data.MyType.Date = data.Date
return data.MyType // will of MyType, and fully populated
```

Note that this only works for unmarshaling. If you need to also marshal this data, a similar trick can be used, but the mechanics around it must be essentially reversed.